# WebBrowser.Refresh problem in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, browser, web-crawler

I'm working on a webcrawler in VB.net, and using the System.Forms.WebBrowser object for handling navigation on sites that use javascript or form posts, but I'm having a problem.  When I navigate backwards (WebBrowser.GoBack()) to a page that was loaded with a form post, the page has expired and I have to do a refresh to resend the request.  When I call a refresh (WebBrowser.Refresh()), a dialog box pops up to confirm.  Is there a way I can get around this modal dialog in code?  Thanks!

Comment: I should also add that I've tried using the WebBrowserRefreshOptions (Normal, Complete, IfExpired) with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to pass in a refresh option of type System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserRefreshOption .

There are several options, described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowserrefreshoption.aspx

It seems that the options are the only way you can control a web browser refresh programmatically.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I did try that, with IfExpired and Completely options selected, as well as the parameterless refresh which I believe is the same as Normal.  I still see refresh prompts

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a popup showing up with a javascript warning. I managed to suppress it using a `window_error` event.

I added this line to the `browser_completed` event handler:

```
((WebBrowser)sender).Document.Window.Error +=
    new HtmlElementErrorEventHandler(Window_Error);
```

Here is my `window_error` event handler:

```
void Window_Error(object sender, HtmlElementErrorEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Another option to think about is toying around with `this._browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed`. I'm pretty sure you aren't getting a script error, but it is worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround/hack to remedy this problem in here: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Q_25160302.html

Basically you do it like this:

```
Browser.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely);
SendKeys.Send("{Enter}");
```

The `SendKeys.Send("{Enter}");` line sends an Enter key to active window, which is the modal dialog we want to get rid of.